# MySQL Error 1111 - Invalid use of group function when nesting window functions

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb, window-functions

I'm working to create a SQL report on `answers` table:

```
id | created_at
1  | 2018-03-02 18:05:56
2  | 2018-04-02 18:05:56
3  | 2018-04-02 18:05:56
4  | 2018-05-02 18:05:56
5  | 2018-06-02 18:05:56
```

And output is:

```
weeks_ago | record_count (# of rows per weekly cohort) | growth (%)
-4        | 21                                         |  22%
-3        | 22                                         | -12%
-2        | 32                                         |   2%
-1        |  2                                         |  20%
 0        | 31                                         |   0%
```

My query is currently erring with:

```
1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT  floor(datediff(f.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
                count(DISTINCT f.id) AS "New Records in Cohort",
                100 * (count(*) - lag(count(*), 1) over (order by f.created_at)) / lag(count(*), 1) over (order by f.created_at) || '%' as growth
FROM answers f
WHERE f.completed_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY weeks_ago
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Can you post a sample data and schema on SQLFiddle or similar websites so that we can try?

Comment: You can't use `COUNT(*)`inside a `LAG` function thats why you get your error..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for that.. any recommendations on how to get this working?

Comment: How should the expected results look like with the current example data?

Comment: i assume if you look 4 weeks ago the range is like..`2018-08-30 to 2018-09-26` ? assuming this date `2018-09-21`

Comment: 4 weeks ago would be a 7 day range, 4 weeks in the past, example: "8/27-9/3"

Comment: Yes then your expected results does not match the example data..And is the max you want to look back 4 weeks?..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'd like to look back to the start of time meaning the oldest answers.created_at record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to find running count of all rows ***excluding*** the current row. I think you can ditch the `LAG` function as follows:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY f.created_at ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) x, -- running count before current row
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY f.created_at) y -- running count including current row
```

You can divide and multiply all you want.

---

Nope. you simply need to separate `GROUP BY` and `LAG OVER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(created_at, CURDATE()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
        COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS new_records
    FROM answers
    WHERE 1 = 1 -- todo: change this
    GROUP BY weeks_ago
    HAVING 1 = 1 -- todo: change this
)
SELECT
    cte.*,
    100 * (
        new_records - LAG(new_records) OVER (ORDER BY weeks_ago)
    ) / LAG(new_records) OVER (ORDER BY weeks_ago) AS percent_increase
FROM cte
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6c86d0f25a08b40af641b6fe1a99195)

Comment: thx but what needs to be in the FROM, WHERE, etc.. to make this work?

Comment: I am unable to run your query because my MySQL does not allow partial group by. I'll try to create a fiddle of data without grouping, hopefully you can figure out the rest.

Comment: ok, I'm not following how to try your suggestion... would you mind updating your answer with the full query so i can follow? really appreciate it!

Comment: thx but that's outputting a row for each record, the idea is each row should be a grouping by week.  So each row includes the total # of answers where answers.created_at was within the week (7 day period). This would allow me to use the query to see how we are performing week over week...

Comment: See revised fiddle; it handles the nested window functions. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=200219656b34d02ee8d1c41a78a46085. Now the thing about grouping... I think you are mixing the window functions and group by incorrectly. But I am feeling tired, sorry.

Comment: hmm, sorry this is still outputting a row per record, not grouping by week. Time for some sleep!

Comment: Nice, this is very promising thank you... the weeks_ago and new_records appears to be computing correctly!

Comment: The one issue is percent_increase... this is being calculated cumulatively and it should be be on a weekly basis. Meaning if last week we had 10 new records, and this week we have 10 new records - that's a 0% percent_increase... is it possible to update your query to account for this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning with `WHERE 1 = 1 -- todo: change this` and `HAVING 1 = 1 -- todo: change this` -- do we need this?

Comment: @AnApprentice `WHERE 1 = 1 ` and `HAVING 1 = 1` are meaningless and can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `lag` contain `COUNT` aggregate function, because It isn't valid when you use aggregate function contain aggregate function.

you can try to use a subquery to make it.

```
SELECT weeks_ago,
       NewRecords "New Records in Cohort",
      100 * (cnt - lag(cnt, 1) over (order by created_at)) / lag(cnt, 1) over (order by created_at) || '%' as growth
FROM (
    SELECT floor(datediff(f.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago, 
           COUNT(*) over(partition by weeks_ago order by weeks_ago) cnt,
           count(DISTINCT f.id) NewRecords,
           f.created_at
    FROM answers f
) t1
```

Comment: thanks but I was trying to get the query to output a row for each record going back to the start of the first record in the db...

Comment: the query above only returns one record

Comment: Ok could you provide some sample data and expect the result? that really help.

Comment: I just updated the question to include example output - not the %s don't actually compute but this should the example desired format... A row per week going back to the start of time in the database for matching records in the answers.created_at

Comment: Thanks for your edit,but I mean could you provide some sample data from `answers`  table. and what's the expect result from your sample data.

Comment: Added some sample data for the answers table, really the only two fields in use are the ID to determine the count (# of records per week row/cohort) and the created_at which should inform the query of which weekly grouping the id belongs to. Does this help?